# How to navigate routes in a functional server component in nextjs app router V13+

Tags: authentication, next.js, server-side-rendering, next.js13

In `pages` I was able to navigate routes on the server by setting up a return statement in getServersideProps()

### Before:

```
export const getServerSideProps = async (context) => {
    try {
    ..........
        // If token exists; redirect to '/' 
        if (token) {
            return {
                redirect: {
                    destination: `/`,
                    permanent: false,
                },
                props: {
                    // email, uid, token
                }
            }

        }

    } catch (err) {
        // either the `token` cookie didn't exist
        // or token verification failed
        // either way: allow user to stay on page to login
        return {
            props: {

            },
        };
    }
};
```

How can I do the same in the `app router` build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could handle this in `middleware.ts`

```
import { getToken } from "next-auth/jwt";

 async function middleware(req) {
   
    const isAuthenticated = await getToken({ req });

    // you implement your logic

   if (!isAuthenticated) {
      return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/login", req.url));
    }
}

// in the same file, you need to specify for which routes tou want to run this middleware

export const config = {
  matchter: ["/", "/dashboard"],
};
```

[middleware docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware)

Comment: That's correct! However, I couldn't use firebase admin module since it uses Node.js specific modules ('os' not supported)

Comment: if you ask a separate question and create a reproducible example i can take a look at it